# Ideas for future topic of the week

Tags: discussion

I'm going to try something new here. I got an idea after observing Space Exploration and Astronomy. Topics of the week often are really good way of getting out a lot of interesting questions *when there are enough visitors to the site in the week to see the topic and respond*. The problem with Astronomy is that a lot of people don't know about the topics of the week because they didn't come up until after the visitor count dropped.

So here's my new idea:

Private beta is too early to actually start **doing** the Topic of the Week activity, *but* it isn't too soon to start coming up with ideas of topics we can do when we *do* start. My thought is that if we come up with topics now, people will look forward to their topic coming up in the Topic of the Week later on and will check back on this site later. It *may* help get a little more visitors later on when the beta experiences the infamous lag period.

With that in mind, **what are your topic ideas?**

(Remember that topics of the week are usually expressed in the form of tags--existing or not.)

---

**UPDATE 1/13/2014**: Aviation, now that you are in public beta and seem to be going strong, do you think you are ready to start a topic of the week? If so, make a new post to start up the topic of the week schedule. Need ideas for format? Check out [Space Exploration](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/452/topic-of-the-week-solar-sail) and [Astronomy](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123/topic-of-the-week-astrometry) Topics of the Week.

Comment: Incidentally these are all probably *excellent* ideas for companion blog posts. That, however, is something that definitely needs to wait until the public beta is gathering some airspeed.

Answer (score 4):

[approaches](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/approaches)

After reading [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/57/what-is-a-simultaneous-offset-instrument-approach-soia), I got the idea that **approaches** could be a really fun topic of the week.

Answer (score 3):

[landing](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/landing)

I would certainly throw **landings** (in all their contentious, everyone does it a different way, do any of us really know how the heck to explain it glory) out there as a topic of the week.

Answer (score 3):

[maintenance](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maintenance) / [aircraft-maintenance](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aircraft-maintenance)

Both preventative maintenance, and the other kind.

Answer (score 2):

[takeoff](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/takeoff)

...and if we're going to talk about approaches and landings we kinda have to talk about takeoffs I guess.
Short field, Soft field, Crosswind, Partial-Power/Reduced-Thrust for you transport-category folks...